# Phone format in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to change the phone format from +XX XXX XXX XXXX into +XXXXXXXXXXXXX. I have a code but everytime I change it it doesn't work locally.

```
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState();
const validatePhone = phone => {
  if (!isValidPhoneNumber(phone)) {
    errors.phone = { type: 'required', message: 'not valid' };
    return;
  }
  delete errors.phone;
  clearErrors('phone');
};
return (
  <>
<PhoneInput
              international
              displayInitialValueAsLocalNumber
              defaultCountry="UA"
              className={classes.phone_input}
              value={phoneNumber}
              onChange={handlePhoneInputChange}
              name="phone"
              id="phone"
            />
)
```

Comment: Where is `PhoneInput` coming from?

Comment: import PhoneInput, { isValidPhoneNumber} from 'react-phone-number-input';

Answer (score 0):

As I understand question you can do it in `onChange` handler like this:

```js
const phone = '+49 123 123 123';
const phone2 = phone.replace(/\s+/g,'');
console.log(phone);
console.log(phone2);
```

Or you need to update validation ?